# Does Docker Desktop run its containers in Windows or in WSL2?

Tags: wsl2, docker-for-windows

**Context** 
I set up a WSL2 running Debian. I run some Docker compose scripts. Everything is contained within WSL2, except Docker Desktop, which I installed on Windows.

Already have I read that it's possible to run Docker in WSL2 without Docker Desktop in Windows. However, I do not understand what happens under the hood when I do use Docker Desktop. Especially since I never (knowingly) installed any docker packages on the Debian instance.

Docker Desktop in Windows shows me which containers are running. Startup and IO happen in the Debian instance.

**Question** 
Do(es) the docker engine/containers run in Windows or inside the WSL2?

Comment: The Docker Windows installation page notes that Docker requires either HyperV or WSL. Images running within WSL2 cannot be shared between user accounts, while using running in HyperV are shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Docker documentation
[Docker Desktop WSL 2 backend on Windows](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/wsl/):

> Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) 2 is a full Linux kernel built by Microsoft, which lets Linux distributions run without managing virtual machines. With Docker Desktop running on WSL 2, users can leverage Linux workspaces and avoid maintaining both Linux and Windows build scripts. In addition, WSL 2 provides improvements to file system sharing and boot time.

The containers are running under WSL2 inside a simplified virtual machine.
The VM itself is executed by Hyper-V that is running on the Windows host.

> Does Docker Desktop run its containers in Windows or in WSL2?

So the answer to the question is actually : "both". It's running under
WSL2 which itself is running under Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though I am confused, isn't Windows a VM under Hyper-V?

Comment: Hyper-V is a Type 2 hypervisor, so Windows runs in the Hyper-V root partition directly on top of the hardware and gives services to Hyper-V and its virtual machines. For the concepts see [Hyper-V architecture](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/cloud-and-networking/9781849688345/1/ch01lvl1sec15/hyper-v-architecture).